# How do I pass data from one component to another in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am working on a quiz app with Angular. I need to get the value of correctAnswersCount in my ResultsComponent. I'm getting the value of 0 for correctAnswersCount in ResultsComponent when I really need the value of the total correct answers at the end of the quiz, and also getting value of 1166 during the quiz in place of correctAnswersCount. I think the code looks correct, just the value that I'm getting is wrong. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is my code:

in my QuizService:

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class QuizService {
      correctAnswersCountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

      sendCountToResults(value) {
        this.correctAnswersCountSubject.next(value);
      }
    }
```

in my DI-Quiz Component:

```
    ngOnInit() {
      this.quizService.correctAnswersCountSubject.subscribe(data => {
        this.count = data + 1;
      });
      this.sendCountToQuizService(this.count); 
    }

    sendCountToQuizService(count) {
      this.quizService.sendCountToResults(count);
    }
```

and in my ResultsComponent:

```
    constructor(private quizService: QuizService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.quizService.correctAnswersCountSubject.subscribe(data => {
        this.correctAnswersCount = data;
      });
    }
```

Please can you help. Thank you.

Comment: How to *Angular passing data from one component to another* use 2 way bindings .

Comment: Why are you creating the observable? You should be able to directly subscribe to the BehaviorSubject in the component and get rid of the observable.

Comment: Yes, I removed the observable, but still getting a value of 0 for the correctAnswersCount...

Comment: Can you add the relationship of your components or even better a StackBlitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you some tips that my help.

- You should use `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root' })` on QuizService to guarantee a singleton instance of this service across the whole app.
- At DI-Quiz Component, call `this.sendCountToQuizService` inside the callback of the subscription.
- At ResultsComponent, init the subscription on the OnInit hook (maybe use pipe async to display the count value).

Edit:

I think you are somehow creating recursive events at DIQuizComponent by subscribing and sending new values to same Subject on the same place.
As correctAnswersCountSubject is a BehaviorSubject, you can get the value of correctAnswersCountSubject without subscribing to it using `getValue` method.

This time i've created a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-quiz), hope this helps.

Edited Again:

I've debugged your code and with some modifications I resolved all problems and they are:

- at `QuizQuestionComponent`, add the decorator @Output() on answer EventEmitter.
- at `DependencyInjectionQuizComponent`, on the nextQuestion method, this.answer is set as null before call the checkIfAnsweredCorrectly method who needs the answer value.
- at `DependencyInjectionQuizComponent`, you are not incrementing the this.count, I did it on the checkIfAnsweredCorrectly method.
- And the most important thing, I removed all providers in the modules to guarantee a singleton instances of the services.

Demo here: [stackblitz](https://angular-9-quiz-app-t2whvj.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thanks. I did all these tips but I'm still getting 0 for the final correctAnswersCount and getting a value of 1166 for the value during the quiz.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using your code but still not able to get it to work. Please could you see my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app

Comment: Great, thank you! One thing I noticed is that a user could potentially answer the question twice (and increasing the count twice) if they go back with previous. Is there a way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Sure, the Material Radio Group has a `disabled` prop, you can bind a flag on it.

Comment: I added disabled="true" to the mat-radio-group, but that disables the entire group. Not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Yep, just add an alreadyAnswered boolean prop to the component initially as false, then after an answer was selected, set the alreadyAnswered to true. And at the html switch `disabled="true"` to `[disabled]="alreadyAnswered"`

Comment: I added this.disabled = true at the end of the setSelected function, but when I go to the next question, all of the options are disabled.

Comment: Should I reset with this.disabled = false inside ngOnChanges?

Comment: I've added mat-checkbox for questions with multiple answers and it seems that setting disabled prevents the form from working correctly. Also oddly, the second question (with the checkboxes) doesn't seem to increment score when answered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data between components you have a couple of options.  I'm not going to assume anything about your scenario and whether these will work, because in reality a lot of times when we are new, we realize that we need to slightly re-architect our components in order to achieve what we want, so instead, I will share the methods available to you.

**Standard Data Binding**

If you are trying to pass data from a parent component to a child component, you can simple bind the data when you add your component to the parent component.

parent.component.html

```
<child-component [myData]="myDataAsIsInParentComponent"></child-component>
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input() myData: <YourType>;
```

**Emitting Data Upwards**

If you are trying to pass data from a child component to a parent component, you can emit your values up the component tree (aka bubbling up the component tree)

parent.componenent.html

```
<child-component (myEmitter)="functionToCallInParent($event)"></child-component>
```

parent.component.ts

```
functionToCallInParent($event) {
  const myPassedData = $event;
}
```

child.component.ts

```
@Output myEmitter: EventEmitter<myType> = new EventEmitter<myType>();
```

Now, those are baked in solutions that come out-of-the box with Angular.

**State Management i.e. Redux, etc.**

I highly suggest that you explore state management solutions like redux via NGRX if you want to have some truly awesome data storage and data passing powers.

NGRX is amazing.  It's a bit intimidating for some at first, but the benefits are insane!  Imagine being in module x and needing data from module y and neither module is connected by a component?  Well you wouldn't be able to to pass the data up and/or down the component tree in that scenario, but you can with redux.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I'm learning RxJS now and have some exposure to NgRx and that's the direction I'm looking to go in. For now, I would like to work on the quiz app and get it to a point where I'm ready to convert it to NgRx.

Comment: @integral100x that's awesome.  I definitely recommend NGRX.  We use it heavily for our public and private applications.  If my answer helped you, please mark it as correct so that it can help others in the future when they come to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution will be using service as store for storing correct answers count.
Please find below solution:

In your service declare one private variable and write getters and setters for it in service as below:

```
private correctAnswerCount:number;

//if you are calling this method for each correct answer
incrementCorrectAnswerCount(){
this.correctAnswerCount++;
}

//if you are calling this method once
setCorrectAnswerCount(value:number){
this.correctAnswerCount = value;
}

//you can fetch this method from any compononent so as the value of correctAnswerCount
getCorrectAnswerCount(){
return this.correctAnswerCount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already gone ahead with the BehaviorSubject approach.